# Use of build-In function in Coq

Tags: coq

I want to use lemma (count_occ_In)related to count_occ function from  library.I have Imported library in the Coq Script. But still I am unable to use it. If I copy count_occ & eq_dec from library in the scipt,then it works. My question is why I should redefine function when I have included library module. Please guide me how to write lemma by adding the library module only(Not defining the functions again)?.

Answer (score 1):

With the additional information this should work for you:

```
Require Import List Arith. 
Import ListNotations.

Check count_occ.

Search nat ({?x = ?y} + {?x <> ?y}).

Definition count_occ_nat := count_occ Nat.eq_dec.
Definition count_occ_In_nat := count_occ_In Nat.eq_dec.

Check count_occ_nat.
Check count_occ_In_nat.
```

See how I used `Check` to find which arguments `count_occ` takes and how I used `Search` to find a suitable instance for the decidability of equality function.

`count_occ` is written like this because it should work for lists of any type with decidable equality, but then to use it, you need a proof that for your type equality is decidable, and you have to give this explicitly.

In modern definitions one makes such arguments implicit and uses type classes to automatically fill in information like decidable equality, but `count_occ` has an explicit argument for that, so you have to supply it.

Comment: Yes, function exist in the library. After print count_occ,I get count_occ = 
fun (A : Type)
  (eq_dec : forall x y : A, {x = y} + {x <> y})
=>
fix count_occ (l : list A) (x : A) {struct l} :
  nat :=
  match l with
  | [] => 0
  | y :: tl =>
      let n := count_occ tl x in
      if eq_dec y x then S n else n ----

Comment: OK, then can you tell us what does not work? An example would help.

Comment: Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith. Require Import List Arith. Import ListNotations.
Variable A : Type.

Hypothesis eq_dec : forall x y : A, {x = y}+{x <> y}.
Fixpoint count_occ (l : list A) (x : A) : nat :=
match l with
| [] => 0
| y :: tl =>
let n := count_occ tl x in
if eq_dec y x then S n else n
end.

Theorem count_occ_In l x : In x l <-> count_occ l x > 0. I want to write above lemma without including eq_dec and count_occ(because i have included library)

Comment: After including libraries (Require Import List Arith. 
Import ListNotations.) I get this message In environment
l : list ?A
x : ?T
The term "l" has type "list ?A"
while it is expected to have type
 "forall x0 y : ?A0, {x0 = y} + {x0 <> y}".

Comment: I have list of natural numbers.Want to apply count_occ function for natural numbers only.